# Modal Dialog Rendered by Handlebars -- Broken by <apex:form> tags

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I'm attempting to create a pop-up form in a visualforce page. The pop-up form is a modal dialog that appears when a button is clicked. The form is templated using Handlebars, and has some input fields inside it. However, when I click the button on the page and the form pops up, it is very broken and displays raw HTML:

[image]

Curious to see if the `<apex:form>` tags had anything to do with it, I removed them (and by extension the `<apex:selectList>` and `<apex:inputField>` tags from the form, since they can only exist inside of `<apex:form>` tags). After I removed these, the form did not break.

I am wondering if there is some reason Handlebars is not able to correctly parse `<apex:form>` tags. I have noticed it has no problem using other Salesforce notation, such as **{!Resource.resource_name}** within Handlebars templates.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page title="vfpage" standardController="case" extensions="my_extension" standardStylesheets="false" id="page1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<apex:stylesheet value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- Handlebars Template -->
<script id="flag_form_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <span class="modal-title">Flag for Review Form</span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <apex:form id="form_flag">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <label>Product:</label>
                            <apex:selectList value="{!case.ProductId__c}" multiselect="false" size="1" id="overr_prod" styleClass="form-control flag-prod">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!productList}" />
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <label>Platform:</label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!case.Platform__c}" id="flag_plat" styleClass="form-control flag-plat" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <label>Client:</label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!case.Game_Client__c}" id="flag_client" styleClass="form-control flag-client" /><br /><br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label>Type your feedback here, then click submit:</label><br />
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="flag_form_text" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </apex:form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitFlagForm()">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<!-- Handlebars Template will render here -->
<div id="flag_form" class="modal fade" role="dialog"></div>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="flagForReview" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#flag_form" title="Flag for Review"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i></button>


<!-- Javascript -->
<apex:includeScript value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>

</apex:page>
```

**Handlebars Javascript:**

```
var flag_form_source = $("#flag_form_template").html();
var flag_form_template = Handlebars.compile(flag_form_source);
var flag_form_html = flag_form_template(context);
$("#flag_form").html(flag_form_html);
```

Comment: Any JavaScript errors in browser console/dev tools?

Comment: No JavaScript errors in the browser console. I ended up finding a different approach that didn't require me to put the form in a Handlebars template, but I'm still curious as to why this issue occurred.